# SCSS (Sass) tslint error when @use and @include mixin with namespaces

Tags: sass, tslint, scss-mixins

Could someone help how to allow namespaces for linter? I'm not able to google anything relevant for my isue with linter in VS Code...

my tslint.json starts with:

```
    {
      "extends": "tslint:recommended",
      "rulesDirectory": [
        "codelyzer"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "at-rule-no-unknown": null,
        "scss/at-rule-no-unknown": true, 
   ...
```

or

```
...
  "rules": {
    "at-rule-no-unknown": [true, {
      "ignoreAtRules": ["mixin"]
    }],
...
```

after this "@use" is OK, but @include < namespace >.< mixin > still cause problems

```
// my.scss
@use "styles/mix" as mi; 
button {
    @include mi.size('10px');
}
```

```
error 1 mi. <--- semi-colon expected
error 2 ...('10px');}  <--- at-rule or selector expected
```

is there a way to allow this?

Comment: You can't have dots/fullstops in your mixin names. each @include calls one mixin. I don't believe you can allow it because that's how SCSS works.

Comment: @NathanielFlick You probably didn't hear about Sass Modules, this is new thing.

Comment: You're right I hadn't heard about it, thx for the tip! I found the spec here, make sure you're following it: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

Comment: Thanks, guys... Yes it is the Sass Module.. I hope i follow spec.. but my question is about linter config in Visual Studio Code - now it's marked as problem, as I described.

Comment: I tried report it: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4901

Comment: It's not only linter :( angular build is impossible with namespaces: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16354